# SKLearn SVM : Different Membership Scores for Same Data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am training an SVM two times, first, data loaded from file and then data directly assigned in the code.

This is my code

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np

X = np.genfromtxt("X.txt",delimiter=" ")
Y = np.genfromtxt("Y.txt",delimiter=" ")

fromFile_clf = svm.LinearSVC()
fromFile_clf.fit(X, Y)
fromFile_dec = fromFile_clf.decision_function([[1,2,2]])

U = [[1,1, 0], [1,-1, -1], [-1,1,1], [-1,-1,1]]
V = [0, 1, 2, 3]

direct_clf = svm.LinearSVC()
direct_clf.fit(U, V)
direct_dec = direct_clf.decision_function([[1,2,2]])

print("Loaded From File")
print("X")
print X
print("Y")
print Y
print("Membership")
print fromFile_dec 


print("\n\nData fed directly")
print("U")
print U
print("V")
print V
print("Membership")
print direct_dec
```

The output of the above code is

```
Loaded From File
X
[[ 1.  1.  0.]
 [ 1. -1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.]
 [-1. -1.  1.]]
Y
[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
Membership
[[  1.33332130e+00  -2.54545042e+00  -9.27855314e-06  -1.71427699e+00]]

Data fed directly
U
[[1, 1, 0], [1, -1, -1], [-1, 1, 1], [-1, -1, 1]]
V
[0, 1, 2, 3]
Membership
[[  1.33332173e+00  -2.54545295e+00  -1.57102577e-05  -1.71425921e+00]]
```

The membership scores from both methods seem to be different and there is a drastic change in the score for the third class. What is wrong here?

Comment: This could be completely off, but I notice the inputs from file are floating point and the ones you pass directly are integer. Have you tried writing your directly-fed inputs as floating point values? (e.g. `1.0` instead of `1`)

Comment: @JesseRusak changed everything to floating point representation. Again the third class have drastic difference in score.

Comment: The numbers you're showing are not really that different. (i.e. if there's an optimization happening under the covers, they're likely within acceptable error.) What happens if you run it on exactly the same data two or three times in a single run of your script?